# Compile Error: END IF Without Block IF (Persistent Error)

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

I really need help with this project that I am working on but I cannot seem to get this error off my back. Could anyone please recommend solutions ?

```
Sub Dsurvey()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    k = 3

    For i = 3 To 22
        j = j + 1
        If Sheets("2").Cells(j, "A").Value - Sheets("2").Cells(i, "A").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(j, "B").Value - Sheets("2").Cells(i, "B").Value Then
            Sheets("2").Cells(k, "J").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(i, "A").Value
            Sheets("2").Cells(k, "K").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(i, "B").Value
            Do While Sheets("2").Cells(k, "J").Value <= Sheets("2").Cells(j, "A").Value
                    Sheets("2").Cells(k, "J").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(k - 1, "J").Value + 100
                    Sheets("2").Cells(k, "K").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(k - 1, "K").Value + 100
                    k = k + 1

        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't so much that you are missing an `End If` , but you are not closing the `Do While` with a `Loop`.

```
k = 3
For i = 3 To 22
    j = j + 1
    If Sheets("2").Cells(j, "A").Value - Sheets("2").Cells(i, "A").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(j, "B").Value - Sheets("2").Cells(i, "B").Value Then
        Sheets("2").Cells(k, "J").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(i, "A").Value
        Sheets("2").Cells(k, "K").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(i, "B").Value
        Do While Sheets("2").Cells(k, "J").Value <= Sheets("2").Cells(j, "A").Value
            Sheets("2").Cells(k, "J").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(k - 1, "J").Value + 100
            Sheets("2").Cells(k, "K").Value = Sheets("2").Cells(k - 1, "K").Value + 100
            k = k + 1
        Loop
    End If
Next i
```

**Debug version:**

```
k = 3
With Sheets("2")
    For i = 3 To 22
        j = j + 1
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(j, "A")) And IsNumeric(.Cells(i, "A")) And IsNumeric(.Cells(j, "B")) And IsNumeric(.Cells(i, "B")) Then
            If .Cells(j, "A").Value - .Cells(i, "A").Value = .Cells(j, "B").Value - .Cells(i, "B").Value Then
                .Cells(k, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                .Cells(k, "K").Value = .Cells(i, "B").Value
                Do While .Cells(k, "J").Value <= .Cells(j, "A").Value
                    .Cells(k, "J").Value = .Cells(k - 1, "J").Value + 100
                    .Cells(k, "K").Value = .Cells(k - 1, "K").Value + 100
                    k = k + 1
                Loop
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not numeric: & " & i & Chr(45) & j & Chr(45) & k
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It now shows type mismatch in my if statement. Any idea of the source of this error ?

Comment: It would seem that at least one of those is not a numerical value; hence the `Type mismatch` where non numerical values cannot be used in mathematical operations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll crosscheck the cells being operated on.

Comment: See my version above that checks for numeric values and outputs to the VBE's Immediate windows (VBE, Ctrl+G) if not.